# Facade design pattern, get attribute from facade

Tags: php, design-patterns, facade

I have something like facade design pattern in my application. We can start this:
http://www.patternsforphp.org/doku.php?id=facade

From example:
Facade = Computer 
Parts: CPU, memory...

And what is the solution this situation: The computer has an ID. Most of parts need not to know about Computer ID, but there is several parts, which communicate with World, eg. Network card, which need to know Computer ID in which is placed.

What to do - what is the best solution?
Thanks for replies.

Comment: If I coded this part of code I did not know, that is facade - it has risen naturally. But this is complication if the code should still very good maintanable and problems with consistency. What if the ID will be changed?

Comment: Can you clarify the question please because right now I dont understand what you are asking at all. A Facade defines a higher-level interface that makes the subsystem easier to use.

Comment: In real: I have static class with method Javascript::addVariable() which carry variable from php to javascript. Some parts of facade need to carry some variables to javascript but in javascript I need assigned these values to computer.

Comment: I have not real facade. But the system of classes is the same as in the example (url) above.

Comment: are you sure that Computer needs ID? May be the ID should be moved to Network card as its Mac address or sort of?

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you want something like this:
You need to send the computerId to the specific part, when you create the specific part and store it private in the object. Like in NetworkDrive.
After that you can use the computerId as you want.

```
class CPU
{
    public function freeze() { /* ... */ }
    public function jump( $position ) { /* ... */ }
    public function execute() { /* ... */ }

}

class Memory
{
    public function load( $position, $data ) { /* ... */ }
}

class HardDrive
{
    public function read( $lba, $size ) { /* ... */ }
}

class NetworkDrive
{
     private $computerId;

     public function __construct($id)
     {
         $this->computerId = $id;
     }

     public function send() { echo $this->computerId; }

}

/* Facade */
class Computer
{
    protected $cpu = null;
    protected $memory = null;
    protected $hardDrive = null;
    protected $networkDrive = null;
    private $id = 534;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cpu = new CPU();
        $this->memory = new Memory();
        $this->hardDrive = new HardDrive();
        $this->networkDrive = new NetworkDrive($this->id);
    }

    public function startComputer()
    {
        $this->cpu->freeze();
        $this->memory->load( BOOT_ADDRESS, $this->hardDrive->read( BOOT_SECTOR, SECTOR_SIZE ) );
        $this->cpu->jump( BOOT_ADDRESS );
        $this->cpu->execute();
        $this->networkDrive->send();
    }
}

/* Client */
$facade = new Computer();
$facade->startComputer();
```

You can use observer pattern to notify the networkDrive object for an eventual changing of computerId

Comment: Yes, this is it. But... I have a bad feel to have "stored" id of computer in several objects instead of one. (consistency - changing id of computer etc.)

Comment: So I think, I need something like pointer to Computer instance in NetworkCard instead of ID. (We can premiss that computer has method getId()).

Comment: when you change the computer id, you can use the observer pattern, and notify the NetworkDrive object to change the stored computerId. Can be a solution. you cannot send a reference, because you can change the value in the networkDrive, and that is not so good. You can send the whole object Computer, and use what you need to use ( $this->networkDrive = new NetworkDrive($this); ). I recommend to use observer pattern

Comment: I understand. It will works. But still, I have question - is there any esier way to get ID of computer from Its part? Without changing constructors. Easy, something like: _((Computer) Computers::getComputerByPart(IPart $this))->getId();_ There isn't pattern (or best practise) for this?

Comment: this looks more difficult to implement, but i think can pe possible.